# Set state in stages react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm trying to set my component's state by defining a series of "steps"/"actions". These actions are objects that define how the state should change. I want to iterate through an array of action objects to update my component's state and reflect those changes in the UI. I'm also trying to make it so these actions occur roughly 1 second apart from each other.

I have made the below example to depecit what I'm trying to do and the issue:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">

const {useState} = React;

const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
const App = ({actions}) => {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState({player1: 20, player2: 20});
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  const handleActions = async () => {
    for(const {takeFrom, amount} of actions) {
      await sleep(1000); // wait 1 second
      console.log(takeFrom, amount, players[takeFrom]); // for debugging (check console)

      // only take what's available so player doesn't have a negative value (0 is min value)
      const maxAmount = Math.min(amount, players[takeFrom]); 

      setCount(currCount => currCount + maxAmount); // pool taken values together
      setPlayers((players) => ({
        ...players, 
        [takeFrom]: players[takeFrom] - maxAmount
      }))
    }
  }
  return <div>
    <p>Count: {count}</p>
    <ul>
      {Object.entries(players).map(([playerId, points]) => 
        <li key={playerId}>{playerId}: {points}</li>
      )}
    </ul>
    <button onClick={handleActions}>Perform actions</button>
  </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App actions={[
  {takeFrom: "player1", amount: 5}, // now player1 has 15 points (20 - 5 )✅
  {takeFrom: "player2", amount: 10}, // now player 2 has 10 points ✅
  {takeFrom: "player1", amount: 20} // now player1 has 0 points (cap the amount) ❌ 
]} />, document.body);

</script>
```

The `actions` passed into the component `<App />` are used to define how the `count` and `players` state should change. Here `{takeFrom: "player1", amount: 5}` means that the `players` state should remove 5 (points) from the key `player1`, as well as update the `count` state to add `5`. I only want to take `5` points from the player if they have those 5 points, if they have less than 5, I'll take what they have remaining and add that to `count`. The above logic inside the `for` loop tries to implement this.

The issue is that there seems to be a closure over the `players` object, so each time my for loop iterates it's accessing the original `players` state and not the updated one which causes the players points to become a negative value.

I'm not sure how to fix this and I'm not too sure if there is a better way to approach this. I've read that setting state in a for loop shouldn't be done, so if there is a better way to achieve this I would appreciate those ideas also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem, is that your players object is not getting updated. Instead of using a `function` while setting a state, a better approach would be to copy the initial state object at the beginning to a new variable and then update this new variable and finally set it to the `players` state.

Like this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
export default function App({ actions }) {
  const { useState } = React;

  const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState({ player1: 20, player2: 20 });
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleActions = async () => {
    let modifiedCount = count;
    let modifiedPlayers = players;
    for (const { takeFrom, amount } of actions) {
      await sleep(1000);
      console.log(takeFrom, amount, modifiedPlayers[takeFrom]); // for debugging (check console)
      // only take what's available so player doesn't have a negative value (0 is min value)
      const maxAmount = Math.min(amount, modifiedPlayers[takeFrom]);
      modifiedCount += maxAmount;
      modifiedPlayers = {
        ...modifiedPlayers,
        [takeFrom]: modifiedPlayers[takeFrom] - maxAmount
      };
      setCount(modifiedCount); // pool taken values together
      setPlayers(modifiedPlayers);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      <ul>
        {Object.entries(players).map(([playerId, points]) => (
          <li key={playerId}>
            {playerId}: {points}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={handleActions}>Perform actions</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here, I have initialized `modifiedCount` and `modifiedPlayers` to `count` and `players`, and then used these variables to update the state.

Check it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-kapitsa-b40gm?file=/src/App.js:0-1312).

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your `handleActions` function as below.

```js
const handleActions = () => {
  let processPlayer = players; // To store the old version of the players
  let finalCount = count; // To store the old version of the count

  actions.forEach((player) => {
    const count = processPlayer[player.takeFrom] - player.amount;
    const maxAmount = Math.min(player.amount, processPlayer[player.takeFrom]);

    finalCount += maxAmount;
    processPlayer[player.takeFrom] = count >= 0 ? count : 0;
  }); // Process them as per the requirement

  setPlayers({
    player1: processPlayer.player1,
    player2: processPlayer.player2
  }); // Merge the result with the players state

  setCount(finalCount); // Merge the result with the count state
};
```

Store player details & count in separate variables & the end of the function merge them with the application state. Here the state updates only once.

https://codesandbox.io/s/actions-loop-68139806-lbsxs

Let me know if you need further support.